# DirectX 9 Terrain Engine Problem C++

Tags: c++, directx

I'm Having a problem with my DirectX 9 Terrain Engine.. It's working fine, except for one thing, it doesn't load the heightmap in a proper way.
You can see a screenshot of the problem here: [alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/240/problemc.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/240/problemc.png)
as you can see there is a diagonal crack through the entire map.. one side should be mirrored to render the map properly.

I'm almost sure the problem is not inside the file, as other programs don't seem to have a problem with it.

I'm loading my heightmap in this way (class header first):

```
class Terrain
{
public:
Terrain(const char* fileName);
~Terrain();
void Update(int x, int y);
void Render(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 Device);

private:
float* Data;
int Width;
int TileWidth;
bool isRendering;
bool isSwapping;
std::vector<Chunk*> RenderChunks;
};
```

and the constructor:

```
Terrain::Terrain(const char* fileName)
{
std::fstream File(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

File.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
int Length = File.tellg();
File.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

int w = (int)sqrt((float)Length/4.0)-1;
Data = new float[Length / 4];
File.read((char*)Data, Length);
File.close();

Width = w;
int dataWidth = w+1;

TileWidth = w/16;
for (int y=0; y<TileWidth; y++)
{
    for (int x=0; x<TileWidth; x++)
    {
        Chunk* c = new Chunk(x*16, y*16, 16, 512, Data);
        RenderChunks.push_back(c);
    }
}
}
```

Whenever I'm calling a height on the heightmap, i use it like this: Data[x + y*dataWidth] (just the usual way)
the Chunk class is a class that just renders a part of the heightmap, just so the detail decreases as the distance to the camera increaes.

So my question is: what could cause my problem?

EDIT: Rendering code:

```
void Terrain::Render(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 Device)
{
for (unsigned int i=0; i<RenderChunks.size(); ++i)
{
    RenderChunks[i]->Render(Device);
}
}
Chunk::Chunk(int cX, int cY, int cW, int dW, float* Data):
    Pos(cX, 0, cY)
{
Heights = new float[(cW + 1) * (cW + 1)];
ParentH = Data;
ParentOffset = cX + cY*dW;
ParentW = dW;
Width = cW + 1;

for (int y=0; y<Width; ++y)
{
    memcpy(Heights + y*Width, Data + cX + (y+cY)*dW, sizeof(float)*Width);
}

Vertices = NULL;
Calculate(16, 16, 16, 16, 16);
}
void Chunk::Calculate(int L, int lod_L, int lod_R, int lod_U, int lod_D)
{
Detail = L;
if (Vertices) delete[] Vertices;

Vertices    = new Vertex[(Width-1)*(Width-1)*6/(L*L)];
Count       = (Width-1)*(Width-1)*2/(L*L);

float Height = 100.0f;
for (int y=0; y<Width-1; y += L)
{
    for (int x=0; x<Width-1; x += L)
    {
        Vertex* thisQuad = Vertices + (y/L)*((Width-1)/L)*6 + (x/L)*6;
        float heights[4] = {
            Heights[(x    ) + (y    )*Width] * Height,
            Heights[(x    ) + (y + L)*Width] * Height,
            Heights[(x + L) + (y    )*Width] * Height,
            Heights[(x + L) + (y + L)*Width] * Height};

        float bonus[8] = {
            heights[0],
            heights[2],
            heights[0],
            heights[2],
            heights[1],
            heights[3],
            heights[1],
            heights[3]};
        if (Pos.z + y > 0)
        {
            bonus[0] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x    ) + ((int)Pos.z + y - L)*ParentW] * Height;
            bonus[1] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x + L) + ((int)Pos.z + y - L)*ParentW] * Height;   
        }
        if (Pos.x + x > 0)
        {
            bonus[2] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x - L) + ((int)Pos.z + y    )*ParentW] * Height;
            bonus[4] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x - L) + ((int)Pos.z + y + L)*ParentW] * Height;
        }
        if (Pos.x + x < ParentW-L-L)
        {
            bonus[3] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x+L+L) + ((int)Pos.z + y    )*ParentW] * Height;
            bonus[5] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x+L+L) + ((int)Pos.z + y + L)*ParentW] * Height;
        }
        if (Pos.z + y < ParentW-L-L)
        {
            bonus[6] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x    ) + ((int)Pos.z + y+L+L)*ParentW] * Height;
            bonus[7] = ParentH[((int)Pos.x + x + L) + ((int)Pos.z + y+L+L)*ParentW] * Height;
        }

        if (x == 0 && lod_L>L)
        {
            heights[0] = lerp(
                Heights[(x    ) + (((y    )/lod_L)*lod_L        )*Width], 
                Heights[(x    ) + (((y    )/lod_L)*lod_L + lod_L)*Width], 
                (float)((y  ) % lod_L) / (float)lod_L) * Height;

            heights[1] = lerp(
                Heights[(x    ) + (((y + L)/lod_L)*lod_L        )*Width],
                Heights[(x    ) + (((y + L)/lod_L)*lod_L + lod_L)*Width],
                (float)((y+L) % lod_L) / (float)lod_L) * Height;
        }
        if (x >= Width-2 && lod_R>L)
        {
            heights[2] = lerp(
                Heights[(x + L) + (((y    )/lod_R)*lod_R        )*Width], 
                Heights[(x + L) + (((y    )/lod_R)*lod_R + lod_R)*Width], 
                (float)((y  ) % lod_R) / (float)lod_R) * Height;

            heights[3] = lerp(
                Heights[(x + L) + (((y + L)/lod_R)*lod_R        )*Width],
                Heights[(x + L) + (((y + L)/lod_R)*lod_R + lod_R)*Width],
                (float)((y+L) % lod_R) / (float)lod_R) * Height;
        }//*/
        if (y == 0 && lod_U>L)
        {
            heights[0] = lerp(
                Heights[(((x    )/lod_U)*lod_U        ) + (y    )*Width],
                Heights[(((x    )/lod_U)*lod_U + lod_U) + (y    )*Width],
                (float)((x  ) % lod_U) / (float)lod_U) * Height;

            heights[2] = lerp(
                Heights[(((x + L)/lod_U)*lod_U        ) + (y    )*Width],
                Heights[(((x + L)/lod_U)*lod_U + lod_U) + (y    )*Width],
                (float)((x+L) % lod_U) / (float)lod_U) * Height;
        }
        if (y >= Width-2 && lod_D>L)
        {
            heights[1] = lerp(
                Heights[(((x    )/lod_D)*lod_D        ) + (y + L)*Width],
                Heights[(((x    )/lod_D)*lod_D + lod_D) + (y + L)*Width],
                (float)((x  ) % lod_D) / (float)lod_D) * Height;

            heights[3] = lerp(
                Heights[(((x + L)/lod_D)*lod_D        ) + (y + L)*Width],
                Heights[(((x + L)/lod_D)*lod_D + lod_D) + (y + L)*Width],
                (float)((x+L) % lod_D) / (float)lod_D) * Height;
        }//*/

        D3DXVECTOR3 fake(0,0,0);
        Vertex p1(D3DXVECTOR3(x,     heights[0], y    ) + Pos, CalcNormal(bonus[2], heights[2], bonus[0], heights[1]));
        Vertex p2(D3DXVECTOR3(x,     heights[1], y + L) + Pos, CalcNormal(bonus[4], heights[3], heights[0], bonus[6]));
        Vertex p3(D3DXVECTOR3(x + L, heights[2], y    ) + Pos, CalcNormal(heights[0], bonus[3], bonus[1], heights[3]));
        Vertex p4(D3DXVECTOR3(x + L, heights[3], y + L) + Pos, CalcNormal(heights[1], bonus[5], heights[2], bonus[7]));

        thisQuad[0] = p1;
        thisQuad[1] = p2;
        thisQuad[2] = p3;

        thisQuad[3] = p3;
        thisQuad[4] = p2;
        thisQuad[5] = p4;
    }
}
}
void Chunk::Render(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 Device)
{
Device->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL);

Device->DrawPrimitiveUP(
    D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST,
    Count,
    Vertices,
    sizeof(Vertex));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is that your chunk class takes a width (cW) and then you assign that value + 1 to the width.  Im further assuming the cW is the number of texels in the heightmap(ie in a 1024x1024 heightmap cW is 1024).  If thats right then by adding 1 each subseqent line will be offset to the left by 1.  As you go on you make the problems worse so by 512 lines you'll be 512 to the left (or starting halfway across the texture).  This would give you the diagonal shear you are seeing.

Comment: it's the dW parameter giving problems

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like the order in which you are building your triangle-strip(s) (or are you using another type of primitive?) has an issue.  Can you post the relevant part of your rendering loop?

Edit: My intuition is that when you're mirroring your terrain data, you're creating criss-crossed geometry down the diagonal because the corners of your terrain quads (if you imagine them as such) are connecting to the corners diagonally across rather than directly across.  I hope that some DirectX / rendering guru can give you a more precise answer based on the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be an "off by 1" error, but the post saying that seems to be deleted somehow..
it was the right solution anyway.